# keydown on body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get alerted whenever I press a key.

I've tried:

```
$('body').live('keyup', function() {
     alert('testing');
});
```

But it doesn't work, could it be because of the selector?

UPDATE:

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../system/media/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('body').live('keyup', function() {
                    alert('testing');
                });   
            });   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            TODO write content
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't alert me when I press something although it works when I replace `keyup` with `mouseover` and mouse over `TODO write content`

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you pressing keys while the mouse is positioned inside a textbox or other input control?

Comment: no..im not having anything focused..just want to press a key and it will autofocus and paste in that keypress in an input field. if i type "hello" i want these to be shown in that input field.

Comment: Your test works for me. Can you give more info, or a demo web-page?

Comment: are u typing inside any input fields? i just click outside and type something, but i get no alert...it works when i type from within a input field or use mouseover instead..

Comment: The above code works for me.  Make sure that the page has focus and also that something is not stopping event propagation (another keyup event handler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `$("html")` or `$("*")` instead of `$("body")`. In order for the `keyUp` event on body to fire, the body node or one of its children must be focused. You can accomplish this in your example by adding a text input and focusing the mouse to that input. What you really want is to capture any key press, so `$("html")` should work.

**Edit**: I think your example might work, but in any case, to run the logic conditionally you might try this:

```
if ($(document.body).is(".focusOnKeypress")) {
   $("html").live(...);
}
```

Or, I think this will also work:

```
$("body:not(.noFocusOnKeypress)").parent("html").live(...);
```

Comment: thanks it worked. how do i select the whole page but not some specific  class. tried $('html:not(.noFocusOnKeypress)') but it didnt work

Answer (score 6):

Just listen to the window!

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: this will not work in IE8 or below. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code. This is working fine.

```
$('body').on('keyup', function() {
     alert('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your page does not have focus.. you need to click on the page first and it will work..

alternatively you could forcibly set the focus to an input element and thus bring focus to the page..

```
$(function(){ $('input_selector_here').focus(); });
```

Comment: i have clicked on the page so it is focused before i type anything...but still doesnt work..i will make another try with another page to see if its something wrong with my current page

Comment: @ajsie If click anywhere but your `<p>` element the event will be registered on the document rather than the body. The body is the same height as the content. Try [listening to the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290672/why-doesnt-keydown-work?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
$(document.body).on('keyup', function (e) {
    alert('In');
}):
```