# Why doesn't keydown work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simple code doesn't work!   http://jsfiddle.net/FPcFn/

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

    switch (e.which){

        case 37: alert("37");
          }  

    });
```

Why? What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Works just fine. Make sure the "result" window has focus before you press the left arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works.  Click in the output window and press the left arrow key.

Answer (score 4):

Use `window` instead of `document`.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
 ..
}
```

PS: Use of `document` is recommended. `keydown` event is available with both document and window. Take a look at [compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html#t01) tables.

Comment: Don't use the window object as ie8 and lower don't support attaching the keydown event to the window object. Using document is the correct way. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html