# ng-keypress works in Android but not on iOS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, keypress, onkeypress

I'm using angularjs and ionic1. Using ng-keypress on device to detect a barcode scanner's scan (like input). It triggers the function on Android, but not in iOS.

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-keypress="$root.testScanner('press', $event)"></body>
```

in js:

```
$rootScope.testScanner = function(type, e) {
   console.log(type,e);
};
```

Comment: Any errors in console??

Comment: no , nothing , it just cannot trigger the function

Comment: try other ones like watch,keyup etc etc

Comment: didn't work , i think to edit it in a hidden input secretly , that will work , but there is keyboard show in screen in ios

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "to detect a barcode scanner's scan (like input)"?  Is the user pressing a key on the ios/android device, or are you trying to detect events from a piece of third-party hardware?

Comment: Meanwhile this may be relevant, since you're attaching keypress to the `<body>` node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226346/keydown-on-body

Comment: yes it's a third-party hardware . i'm using barcode scanner to get string , and every character trigger ng-keypress once. The situation is android work and iOS not unless i focus a input